# Easytether and Gingerbread?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, tethering

I use a nifty little app called Easytether to tether my Andorid to my Macbook Pro so I can use my Macbook's browser, and get full websites.  Will the Gingerbread upgrade affect the operation of this app?

Comment: What device and carrier?  Normally your carrier decides whether tethering is enabled on a device, and some have turned it off via updates.

Comment: @JohnFretz Just a note: Before Gingerbread, I had EasyTether, however my carrier would no longer allow me to update the application in the market. With Gingerbread, I noticed the market had another version of EasyTether (also by Mobile Stream) so I uninstalled the old one and installed the new one.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, not at all. I use easytether pro on my evo4g, which has the gingerbread update, and I use it for my pc, and my ps3, If im over a friends house.